# Clean python strings, multiple and different characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings like:

```
"\n\n\n  Text1 test2 text3 \n "
"\n  Text1 test2 text3  "
"   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \n\r"
"   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \t\n\r"
"  \n   Text1 test2 \n text3  "
```

I tried using strip or replace, but with them I can target only specific configuration.

What I want is to clean everything before and after alpha-numeric characters.

I have two cases: 
- want to preserve the new lines inside the text
- no new lines preserve even inside the text

Also in case if there are 2 or more spaces inside the text, to remain only one.

Comment: `str.strip()` without any arguments passed removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Try this `"\n\n\n  Text1 test2 text3 \n ".strip()`

Comment: So you don't want the space too between two words?

Comment: @GurkiratSingh, updated the description, to be more clear.

Comment: @NChauhan, I know, the problem is that the text start and end can have multiple combinations, not necessary starts with space.I tried strip but it fixes only some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
import re

strs = [
    "\n\n\n  Text1 test2 text3 \n ",
    "\n  Text1 test2 text3  ",
    "   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \n\r",
    "   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \t\n\r",
    "  \n   Text1 test2 \n text3  ",
]

for s in strs:
   # Clean left-right
   s = s.strip()
   # Clean in the middle
   for char in [" ", "\r", "\t", "\n"]:
       s = re.sub(rf"([{char}])[{char}]*", r"\1", s)
   print(repr(s))
```

Explanation:

- First remove unwanted characters from beginning and end
- Then for every character you want to deduplicate, remove duplicates

Output:

```
$ python3 /tmp/test.py
'Text1 test2 text3'
'Text1 test2 text3'
'Text1 test2 text3'
'Text1 test2 text3'
'Text1 test2 \n text3'
```

Note that in the last case, both the space and the new line were preserved

Comment: It is still unclear to me if you want to preserve new lines in the string or not... but the code above can be easily modified to `re.sub` or `str.replace` the new lines if needed

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s1 = "\n\n\n  Text1 test2 text3 \n "
s2 = "\n  Text1 test2 text3  "
s3 = "   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \n\r"
s4 = "   \n  Text1 test2 text3  \t\n\r"

m = re.match("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",s1)
print(m[1])

m = re.match("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",s2)
print(m[1])

m = re.match("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",s3)
print(m[1])

m = re.match("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",s4)
print(m[1])
```

Or, more generally, to strip string s:

```
s = re.match("^\s*(.*?)\s*$",s)[1]
```

If you need to retain internal newlines and collapse spaces, try:

```
s = re.sub(r"\ +"," ", s.strip())
```

Comment: if "\n" is inside the text will trigger an error, how to ignore it ? What about removing multiple spaces between text ?

Comment: You have now added two new cases, so I've edited the answer to accommodate the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression:

```
import re
string = "" #Any string here
result = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', string)
print(result)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with `\W` and positive look-ahead `(?=\w)` or look behind `(?<=\w)` in order to clear characters at the start and end of the string:

```
s = re.sub(r'^\W+(?=\w)', '', s)  # clear the beginning of the string
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\W+$', '', s)  # clear the end of the string
```

If you don't want to preserve new line characters even inside the text, just follow the above code with a `s.replace('\n', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

just use .strip() method.

```
"\n\n\n  Text1 test2 text3 \n ".strip()
```

There is also rstrip() for right only and lstrip() for left only to be stripped.